# How to hash multiple values including array keccak256 Solidity v5.0.x and web3 'Autodetection of array types is not supported.'

Tags: solidity, web3js, hash, solidity-0.5.x

How can I receive the same hash in solidity and web3?
Multiple values where one is a multi dimensional array.

Solidity v0.5.x:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Hash{

    uint256[][] public data;

    function append(uint _a, uint _b) public {
        data.push([_a, _b]);
    }

    function hash(uint256 _idx, string memory _b) public view returns(bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(data[_idx], _b));
    }
}
```

Solidity output:

```
decoded input   
{
     "uint256 _idx": "0",
     "string _b": "a"
}

 decoded output     
{
"0": "bytes32: 0x8385585c10cea4e82d9662964b0a952bc1ad925ded1aff4ab359eb38b6d23d11"
}
```

Web3:

```
truffle(development)> var arr = new Array(2);
truffle(development)> arr.push([1, 2]);
truffle(development)> web3.utils.soliditySha3(arr,"a")
```

Web3 output:

```
/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:345535
        throw new Error('Autodetection of array types is not supported.');
```

I also tried

```
web3.utils.keccak256(
   web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(["uint256[][]", "string"], [arr, "a"])
);
```

which provides a different hash.

Comment: The error you are receiving is unrelated to the function you posted.

Comment: @shane it's seems like that soliditySha3 doesn't take multiple arguments, error does not throw when using `web3.utils.soliditySha3(a);`

Comment: Updated with more explicit problem and error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good and using `soliditySha3` is the way to go in my opinion.

The thing with this function is that it will work with objects like `number`, `string`, `boolean` but for more complex objects, you need to specify the type.

If you look at the definition of `soliditySha3`, it's expecting an array of `Mixed` type, which is defined as:

```
export type Mixed =
    | string
    | number
    | BN
    | {
          type: string;
          value: string;
      }
    | {
          t: string;
          v: string | BN | number;
      }
    | boolean;
```

So, if you want to pass an array as you are attempting, you need to use an object with `type` and `value` like so:
`web3.utils.soliditySha3({ type: 'uint256[]', value: arr },"a")`

Answer (score 0):

Without an example is not easy to provide a specific answer, but I will try with a simple case.

Assuming a `uint` array. If you want to pass the multidimensional array as a parameter you need to use `pragma experimental ABIencoderV2`. Here I only pass one element of the array.

Solidity code:

```
uint[][] data;

function append(uint _a, uint _b) public {
    data.push([_a, _b]);
}

function hash(uint _idx, string memory _b) public view returns(bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(data[_idx], _b));
}
```

After append `_a = 1` and `_b = 2` for the first index.

```
data[0] = [1,2]
```

Probably you need to do some things with the array depending on the purpose of your code.

Web3 output:

```
truffle(development)> web3.utils.soliditySha3(1,2,"a")
'0x8385585c10cea4e82d9662964b0a952bc1ad925ded1aff4ab359eb38b6d23d11'
```

Solidity output:

```
decoded input   
{
     "uint256 _idx": "0",
     "string _b": "a"
}

 decoded output     
{
"0": "bytes32: 0x8385585c10cea4e82d9662964b0a952bc1ad925ded1aff4ab359eb38b6d23d11"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This really helps. However, I would like to have a huge array like data[1000][1000] and pass this as an arg to the soliditySha3 function. I updated my problem.